# Застопился, хелп

Tags: java

Задание следующее:
Напишите метод evenArray который принимает целое число типа int и возвращает массив заполненный четными числами от 1 до этого числа.

**Пример ввода:** 8
**Пример вывода:** [2,4,6,8]

мой код:

```
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number=sc.nextInt();
    int[] evenArray =new int[number/2];
    for(int i = 0;i<evenArray.length;i++){
        evenArray[i]=i*2;
        System.out.println(evenArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Например, ввожу 8- выводит {0,2,4,6}
Вопрос в том, как мне сделать так, чтобы вместо нуля- выводилась 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number=sc.nextInt();
    int[] evenArray =new int[number/2];
    for(int i = 0;i<evenArray.length;i++){
        evenArray[i]=(i+1)*2;
        System.out.println(evenArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как по мне, то так проще:

```
int[] result = IntStream.range(1, number+1).filter(i->i%2==0).toArray();
```